# Apply CSS to specific post in Wordpress PHP Loop

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using a WPquery loop in order to pull in my articles for a certain category. The articles in the loop are separated with padding and a border. The problem is I wish to have no padding on the first article and no border on the last article.

The loop I am referring to is on the right of the screenshot. How can I do this?

[*Image of Loop*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwl9T.png)

```css
.article-style {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-row">

<?php
$args = array(
 'category_name' => 'weekly',
 'offset' => 1,
 'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$query = new WP_query ( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

 <section class="block-row">
 
  <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="article-style">

  <div class="thumbnail-clmn-right">
   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   
     <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(
      100,
      'alt' => get_the_title()
      ) );
     ?>
    
    </a>
  </div>

   <?php }?>
   
   <h3 class="clmn-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

   <div class="clmn-excerpt"> 
   <?php the_excerpt( array (
    'class' => 'clmn-excerpt'
   )); ?>
   </div>
    </article>
  
    <?php endwhile; ?>
 
   </section>
  
<?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: `.article-style:first-child { padding-top: 0; }` is the easy way. Other methods exist (sibling combinator, knows as lobotomised owl, for example).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Thank you very much, far easier than I expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:first-child` to select first article, and `:last-child` to select last article

here is the code

```
// remove padding from first article
.article-style:first-child {
    padding: 0;
}

//remove border from last article
.article-style:last-child {
    border: 0;
}
```